# Can't get TextView to display text from txt file

Tags: java, android

I'm a novice programmer and may be getting ahead of myself, but the code I have written so far seems not to work and I've been trying to figure it out for hours

The problem is that, when I run this app the TextView still shows up empty.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
// GUI controls
TextView thoughtLogView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set MainActivity.xml as user interface layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // bind GUI elements with local controls

    thoughtLogView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logTextView);
}

private String GetPhoneAddress() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "mythoughtlog.txt");
    if (!file.exists()){
        String line = "Need to add smth";
        return line;
    }
    String line = null;
    //Read text from file
    //StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }

    final TextView tvphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logTextView);
    String saved_phone = GetPhoneAddress();
    if (saved_phone.length()>0){
        tvphone.setText(saved_phone);
    }
    return line;
}
```

And here's the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="top|center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="242dp"
    android:layout_height="227dp"
    android:id="@+id/logTextView"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|center">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="New Log"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:onClick="onNewLogButtonClick"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You aren't calling `GetPhoneAddress()` method.

Comment: call  **GetPhoneAddress()** method in your onCreate

Answer (score 1):

Your not at calling `GetPhoneAddress()` Thats the reason you are not able to set the text. so change your code this way.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set MainActivity.xml as user interface layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // bind GUI elements with local controls

    thoughtLogView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logTextView);
    GetPhoneAddress();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the String result from method `GetPhoneAddress()` only after the full method executed.

> The problem is that, when I run this app the TextView still shows up empty.

It's because you have no value in `saved_phone` and you are not calling `GetPhoneAddress()` either, So I suggest you to move these lines of codes outside the method `GetPhoneAddress()`, call it properly and check the String before setting it to `TextView`.

```
String saved_phone = GetPhoneAddress();
    if (saved_phone.length()>0){
        tvphone.setText(saved_phone);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this line into

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
GetPhoneAddress();
final TextView tvphone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logTextView);
String saved_phone = GetPhoneAddress();
if (saved_phone.length()>0){
    tvphone.setText(saved_phone);
}

}
```

Problem is what you are currently trying to get returning string from method itself GetPhoneAddress() before return statement so it will return nothing ,you need to set text after call of GetPhoneAddress() and you can achieve that as above